# Widgets Not Removed By Grid_forget()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Working off of the [Minimal App from the Tkinter Docs](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/minimal-app.html), I've added a function that the button calls when pressed. The function simply displays a Label in the window. When I press the button a second time, I want it to remove the old Label and display a new Label. Instead `grid_forget()` is not removing the Label and it just repeats the Label on a new row.

Why is the Label widget not removed from the window? The code below illustrates the problem. I've read countless questions on here about removing widgets from display and using grid_forget().

The only thing I could think of was that the widget may be a local variable to `displayText()` and each time it is called by the button press, no `display` variable exists yet and the exception is raised. I tried making `display` a global variable, but it didn't work.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def displayText():
    try:
        display.grid_forget()
        display.destroy()
    except UnboundLocalError:
        #Display will not exist on first button press
        pass

    label = 'Hello World'
    display = tk.Label(text=label)
    #Also tried called display.grid_forget() here
    display.grid()
    display.bell()

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(self):
        top=self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.geometry('300x100+50+50')
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.check = tk.Button(self, text='Say Hi', command=lambda : displayText())
        self.check.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)

app = Application()
app.master.title('Test App')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `display` is indeed a local variable; the moment the function exits, you lose any reference to the label, so cannot do anything further with it.  Making it global is a reasonable solution; "it didn't work" is an utterly useless description of the problem.

Comment: your reference to `display` is lost every time you finish the `displayText()` method, hence you will always get an `UnboundLocalError`. Try including a `print` statement within your error catch, you'll see that it is called every time.

Comment: moreover, why are you trying to delete and create a new `Label` every time? It would be much more sensible to update the existing label, if that's ultimately what you're after.

Comment: It didn't work, as in it didn't do anything differently then when it was not a global variable. I declared `display` as a global variable after the `import` statements. Is that not the correct place to create a global variable?

Comment: Don't hide the exception. It's telling you something important.

Comment: Why are you creating this function outside of `Application`? It seems odd to try to encapsulate your application in a class, and then use non-class methods to insert widgets.

Comment: @asongtoruin I did switch to using `.configure(text=label)`. It is working now, but I declared `display` as a global variable inside the `createWidgets(self)` function. Not sure that is the proper place

Comment: note: there is no point in using lambda here: `command=lambda : self.displayText())`. IMHO lambda should be avoided unless it's necessary, and it's definitely not necessary here. Just do `command=self.displayText`

Comment: @BryanOakley Good point, that was a mistake from combining two programs. I used to have a function that I just ran in the command line, I pasted in the Tkinter GUI code I was trying at the end.

Comment: @BryanOakley I previously had `command=self.displayText())` and it immediately ran `displayText()` when the window opened. Other answers on here said to use `lambda`. I asked for further explanation on what that is doing, but haven't heard yet, so I've just been using it that way.

Comment: @Matt: notice that I did _not_ say to use `command=displayText()`. I said `command=self.displayText` (note the missing `()`). The `command` attribute requires a _callable_. This is the normal way to use the `command` parameter. Using `lambda` is a special case for when you need to pass additional arguments. In this case you don't need to pass any additional arguments.

Comment: @BryanOakley I saw that and it worked, thanks. To clarify, if the function was `displayText(self, text)`, it would be acceptable to use `command=lambda : self.displayText(label)`?

Comment: Found a good resource explaining the `command` attribute and callbacks for others new to Tkinter who come across this question. http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm

Comment: @Matt: you must provide a _callable_. You can use a function with no arguments, or use `lambda` or `functools.partial` to create a new callable that can pass arguments. If you design your code correctly there is almost never a need to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the widget `display` to the main class in `def __init__()`, and move the function as a method. The goal is to keep a control on the widget during the time the app is running.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()
        self.display = None

    def createWidgets(self):
        top=self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.geometry('300x100+50+50')
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.check = tk.Button(self, text='Say Hi', command=self.displayText) 
        self.check.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)

    def displayText(self):
        if self.display:
            self.display.configure(text='hello new world')

        else:
            label = 'Hello World'
            self.display = tk.Label(text=label)
            #Also tried called display.grid_forget() here
            self.display.grid()
            self.display.bell()

app = Application()
app.master.title('Test App')
app.mainloop()
```